# FileTransfer is undefined in Cordova

Tags: file, cordova, visual-studio-2013, file-transfer, cordova-plugins

I am working on Cordova tool in Visual studio.
I want to download files via given url, So for that I have installed File and FileTransfer plugins in application.
But it is giving me eror that,
FileTransfer is undefined.
I am writing it after device load.

I read somewhere that I need to activate requestFileSystem first, so I have also tried this code, but fail.

```
window.requestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT, 0,
            function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
                fileSystem.root.getFile(
                //create a dummy file to get paths
                "dummy.html", { create: true, exclusive: false },
                function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
                    var sPath = fileEntry.toURL().replace("dummy.html", "");
                    alert("Path = " + sPath);
                    //invoke the method to transfer files
                    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
                    //remove the dummy file
                    fileEntry.remove();

                    //and now, we can download
                    fileTransfer.download("http://192.168.2.32:8080/MOBILEHRServices/leaveNotifications/getAttachments/2833739", sPath,
                    function (theFile) {
                        alert("Succ");
                    },
                    function (error) {
                        alert("Err");
                    }
                );
                },
                fail);
            },
        fail);
```

Second code is,

```
alert("Start");
        var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
        fileTransfer.download("http://192.168.2.32:8080/MOBILEHRServices/leaveNotifications/getAttachments/2833739", sPath,
            function (theFile) {
                alert("Succ");
            },
            function (error) {
                alert("Err");
            }
        );
```

In both above code FileTransfer() undefined...

Do I need to add anyrhing else too in solution. ?

My config file is,

in visual studio, We can add plugins via wizard... 
File and FileTransfer plugins...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<widget xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:vs="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/htmlapps" id="io.cordova.down" version="1.0.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets">
  <name>down</name>
  <description>A blank project that uses Apache Cordova to help you build an app that targets multiple mobile platforms: Android, iOS, Windows, and Windows Phone.</description>
  <author href="http://cordova.io" email="dev@cordova.apache.org">Apache Cordova Team </author>
  <content src="index.html" />
  <access origin="*" />
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
  <preference name="windows-target-version" value="8.0" />
  <preference name="windows-phone-target-version" value="8.1" />
  <vs:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" version="1.3.1" />
  <vs:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" version="0.4.6" />
  <vs:platformSpecificValues />
</widget>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Did you declare it as globally??may be this will cause the problem

Comment: No, its not working at all.

alert("Start");
var filesys = new FileTransfer();
alert("Completed");

Here, Completed message not coming...

Comment: I added it in my question. and if possible then tell me what I need to pass in sPath variable as path in second code. ?

Comment: So this will be call after deviceready event??

Comment: yes on index.html page.

Comment: Which plugin is used put the link

Comment: question updated with config file

Comment: Make sure that you attach the js file (you can find it in plugin's www folder) so this will cause the problem if everything is fine clean tthe project and run it

Comment: Are you running this on a mobile device? If you are debugging in a browser, the plugins aren't going to be loaded. You could try running `cordova prepare` to make sure that the platform project is up to date.